# Update object inside array of Objects MongoDB

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

Hello how to update object field inside array of objects in MongoDB collection?
Structure of document is like this:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("60ebee6c2d610c17e4df2445")
languages: [ {code:"eng", word:"house", diff:23}, {code:"deu", word:"Hause", diff:6} ]
}
```

I tried with this query:

```
for (const sent of temparray) {
            try {
                Content.update({_id : sent.id , 'languages.code':'eng'} , { $set: 
                        {
                            'languages.$.word' : sent.min.word
                        } 
                    })
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('error updating document:', err)
            }
        }
```

I want to update field `word` in each `eng` sentence.

I'm using node js and express server.

But nothing happened any idea whats wrong?

Comment: where are you execute this query? nodejs, mongodb shell etc.?

Comment: @turivishal I updated question...it's node js and express server

Comment: try to wrap in async/await, put await before query `await Content.update(`, and async before method name.